# Произошла неизвестная ошибка Unity

Tags: unity3d, плагин

[image: Произошла неизвестная ошибка]

Подскажите как решить проблему:
Использую плагин [Unity google play services](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)
Версию 0.9.64
При добавлении рекорда происходит неизвестная ошибка.
Кодинг:

```
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class GoogleServices : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button buttonOpenLeaderbord;
    public Button buttonOpenAchievment;

    private static readonly string recordId = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQCA";

    #region Prograss
    private static string PrograssRecordIdOne { get; set; } = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQAg";
    private static string PrograssRecordIdTwo { get; set; } = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQAw";
    private static string PrograssRecordIdThree { get; set; } = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQBA";
    private static string PrograssRecordIdFour { get; set; } = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQBQ";
    private static string PrograssRecordIdFive { get; set; } = "CgkI3q-kkKcREAIQBg";
    #endregion

    private enum NamePrograss
    {
        T10 = 10,
        T50 = 50,
        T100 = 100,
        T150 = 150,
        T200 = 200
    }
    private static int[] PrograssCount { get; } =
    {
        (int)NamePrograss.T10,
        (int)NamePrograss.T50,
        (int)NamePrograss.T100,
        (int)NamePrograss.T150,
        (int)NamePrograss.T200
    };

    public void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool soccess) =>
        {
            if (soccess)
            {
                buttonOpenAchievment.interactable = true;
                buttonOpenLeaderbord.interactable = true;
                buttonOpenAchievment.onClick.AddListener(() => LoadAchievment());
                buttonOpenLeaderbord.onClick.AddListener(() => LoadLiderboard());
                SavePrograss(PrograssCount.Length);
                SaveRecord();
            }
            else
            {
                buttonOpenAchievment.interactable = false;
                buttonOpenLeaderbord.interactable = false;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void LoadLiderboard() => Social.ShowLeaderboardUI();

    public static void LoadAchievment() => Social.ShowAchievementsUI();

    public static void SaveRecord() => Social.ReportScore(Record.MaxRecord, recordId, (callback) => { });

    public static void SavePrograss(int sumPrograss = 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sumPrograss; i++)
        {
            if (Record.MaxRecord > PrograssCount[i])
                Social.ReportProgress(HandlePrograss(i), 100, (callback) => { });
        }
    }

    public static string HandlePrograss(int index)
    {
        string id = "";

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0: id = PrograssRecordIdOne; break;
            case 1: id = PrograssRecordIdTwo; break;
            case 2: id = PrograssRecordIdThree; break;
            case 3: id = PrograssRecordIdFour; break;
            case 4: id = PrograssRecordIdFive; break;
        }
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: В логах должно быть что-нибудь написано

Comment: Вот ошибка из логов:06-08 20:38:59.495: E/Volley(5295): [293] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/leaderboards/scores?language=ru-RU